# Why is my "if" statement always determined to be TRUE?

Tags: php, forms, button, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a debug script to test my cookies, but for some reason it always runs the script to delete all the cookies, even when the conditions aren't met. Here's my code - it's all html and php:

```
<form id="cookietest" name="CookieTest" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="createcookie" value="Create cookie" />
    <input type="submit" name="removecookie" value="Remove cookie" />
    <input type="submit" name="removeallcookies" value="Remove all cookies" />
</form>
<?php
    $Domain = thedomain.com
    if($_POST['createcookie'] == TRUE)
    {
        $expire = 60*60*24*14 + time();
        setcookie('TestCookie', 'IExist', $expire, '/', $Domain);
        echo 'TestCookie should have been created. See its value below.<br />';
    }
    if($_POST['removecookie'] == TRUE)
    {
        $expire = time() - 60*60*24*14;
        setcookie('TestCookie', 'IExist', $expire, '/', $Domain);
        echo 'TestCookie should have been deleted. See its value below.<br />';
    }
    if($_POST['removeallcookies'] == TRUE);
    {
        $expire = time() - 60*60*24*14;
        setcookie('TestCookie', 'IExist', $expire, '/', $Domain);
        setcookie('Cookie1', '', $expire, '/', $Domain); // destroys persistent cookie
        setcookie('Cookie2', '', $expire, '/', $Domain); // destroys persistent cookie
        setcookie('Cookie3', '', $expire, '/', $Domain); // destroys persistent cookie
        echo 'All specified cookies should have been removed. <br />';
    }
    if($_POST['createcookie'] == FALSE && $_POST['removecookie'] == FALSE)
    {
        echo 'Neither the cookie create nor cookie remove button was clicked.<br />';
    }
    echo "The contents of 'TestCookie':";
    echo "${_COOKIE['TestCookie']}<br />";
    echo "The cookie array<br />";
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Use `if(isset($_POST['fieldName']){..}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have added  `semi-colon`  after if condition that's why your if block is not executed

```
if($_POST['removeallcookies'] == TRUE);  //<<< semi-colon
```

Comment: @knoell8504 : well, it happens sometimes

Comment: I think you mean the block IS executed always, not is not. The semicolon will cause the block to always execute, not prevent it.

Comment: @MrCode : i mean semicolon causes the body of the if statement to be empty

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use **isset** instead of just a ==

```
if(isset($_POST['createcookie']) )
{
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that a lot. What exactly is the reason for doing it that way?

Comment: **$_POST['createcookie']** would be equals to "Create cookie", the name value in the input is the key in the $_POST and the value is the value (atleast i think so)

Answer (score 0):

As @Cthulhu Said Instead Use:

For Checking that it is set:

```
if(isset($_POST[index])){


// do something

}
```

For Checking that it is not set:

```
if(!isset($_POST[index])){


// do something

}
```